# use of "else if" in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have two questions -
(I)

```
code-fragment-1

if(<condition-statement>){
}

else if(<condition-statement-2>){
    //statements-1
}
//statements-2
```

code-fragment-2

```
if(<condition-statement>){
}

else{
    if(<condition-statement-2>){
        //statements-1
    }
    //statements-2
}
```

Are the above two code fragments same?

(II) when are `else if`s (in C++) used?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only difference is in example 1 your Statement2 will get executed regardless of the conditions you check.  In example 2, Statement2 will only get executed if your `if` condition is false.  Other than that, they're basically the same.

Answer (score 10):

No, in the first case you execute the else block only if the `<condition-statement>` *is not verified* AND *only if* `<condition-statement-2>` *is verified*.

In the second case you execute the else block simply if the `<codition-statement>` is *not verified*.

In this case are equivalent *until* you does not have any //statements-2.

About the question : when is the else if (in c++) used ?

Is used basically under the same conditions of all other languages​​ that have this construct.
`else` is executed as alternative to the related if, `else-if` is executed as alternative but with an 'attached' `if` to be verified, otherwise is not executed.
So they are not logically equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

the syntax of an `if` is really

```
if(condition) statement;
```

What the `{}` really do is allow you to group together multiple statements. In your second example you only have one statement(the if) inside your `{}`s, so yes, both examples are the same, except //statements-2 always gets run when !=true

Answer (score 1):

In your first code sample, statement-2 is executed unconditionally. In the second it is conditional. Not the same.

'else if' is generally to be preferred, because you can keep inserting or appending more of them indefinitely, or append an 'else', whereas with the other form you have to endlessly mess around with braces to get the same effect, and you risk altering the semantics, as indeed you have done in your second sample.

Comment: a switch statement is always to preferre to multiple "else if" branches, or am i getting the wrong idea

Comment: @clockw0rk yes, but only if the conditions are all testing the same variable, and are values that can be used as case labels i.e. not strings.